# Push to array without Quotes, or remove quotes from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically build an array that will eventually look like this

```
var data2 = [
    [gd(2013, 5, "23"), 33], [gd(2013, 5, 24), 41], [gd(2013, 5, 25), 29], [gd(2013, 5, 26), 12], [gd(2013, 5, 28), 17]
];
```

The rest of the code is very hacky from this point onwards as I want it to work before actually making it streamlined...

I build my string like it is above

```
varData = '[gd(' + thisYear + ',' + thisMonth + ',' + thisDay + '),' + thisInt + ']';
```

Then I push it to the array data2

```
data2.push(varData);
```

This created the array that outputs this -

```
["[gd(2013,23,5),4]", "[gd(2013,24,5),41]", "[gd(2013,28,5),4]"]
```

How would I get that same array without the "'s around each index? Or am I going about this in COMPLETELY the wrong way? I don't have too much experience with using arrays in this way, so I'm not sure if it could be built dynamically, or even where to begin.

Edit/Update:
The missing gd function!!

```
function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime();
}
```

Comment: what kind of expression is gd()?

Comment: You're almost certainly going about this the wrong way. What is `gd`?

Comment: `gd(2013, 5, "23")` is not a valid value, it should be a string

Comment: So you want it to appear when outputted by the console to not show the `"` in there (which wouldn't make much sense) or do you actually want that to be an array?  Also do you want the `gd(...), thisInt` bit stored as a string or as 2 actual elements?

Comment: *[XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?*

Comment: Sorry, I missed out an important piece of code. Updated the question with the missing gd function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want exactly what you have in the first example, then you would build that like this:

```
var data2 = [];

// For each item:
data2.push([gd(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay), thisInt]);
```

Comment: I had no idea it was possible to build each array item in such a way! This looks like exactly what I was asking for(and tbh, I should've picked up on this as it is actually pretty simple)!!

Answer (score 1):

Just push the array directly and not in form of a string:

```
data2.push( [ 'gd(' + thisYear + ',' + thisMonth + ',' + thisDay + ')', thisInt ] );
```

Comment: Thanks! You got in just before Dark Falcon, so you get the answer! Thank you again, can't believe I didn't pick up on this, it's so easy... I like to think I'm a decent programmer, but sometimes there are just little things you miss.

Comment: @Gary Kenyon, please note that his answer and mine are not the same. They do different things. His adds a string to the array, while mine calls the `gd` function.

Comment: @GaryKenyon Both answers differ significantly! In my solution I push in strings `"gd(2013,05,28)"` while in Dark Falcon's answer the result of a function call is put in the array. So you have to decide, what it is, you actually want!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it is the result of the function call that I need. Thank you again for the help!!